# QGIS r.watershed ERROR: Raster map or group not found

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

Yesterday I was able to run the r.watershed tool multiple times without any issues, today it's failing every time with "**ERROR: Raster map or group not found**".  I am running the same DEM with the same parameters.  This is in QGIS 2.18 but I get a similar error when attempting the same in QGIS 3.

I completely uninstalled and re-installed QGIS but this did not help.  Any solutions on how to fix this?

EDIT:
I decided to run this in GRASS itself and there are no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw similar error with QGIS 2.18.19, when I left `Minimum size of exterior watershed basin` option (default value: `0`) untouched. (It sets `threshold` option to `"0"` in `g.region` command).

Looking at the log, it led to return an error `The basin threshold must be a positive number` and the job then terminated with the error `Raster map or group not found`.

(Have not checked QGIS 3.0.2.)

Comment: thanks. it was a related issue. I was accidentally leaving both min and max threshold values at default.